# Reverse [down-votes]/[up-votes] synonyms to [downvotes]/[upvotes] on Meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms, meta

We have a [tag synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/down-votes/synonyms) that retags several tags, including [downvotes](/questions/tagged/downvotes), to [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes), and the same is true for [upvotes](/questions/tagged/upvotes) and [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes).

[downvotes](/questions/tagged/downvotes), however, is the better tag because *downvotes* is more commonly used than *down votes*, and likewise, the same is true for [upvotes](/questions/tagged/upvotes).

MSO search:

[downvotes - 1051 results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22downvotes%22) vs. [down votes - 499 results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22down+votes%22)
[upvotes - 1781 results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22upvotes%22) vs.
[up votes - 497 results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22up+votes%22)

Wiktionary has entries for [downvote](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/downvote) and [upvote](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upvote), but none for "down vote" or "up vote".
And, um, even the [tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/down-votes/info) [wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/up-votes/info) uses the one-word form.

Could we reverse these tag synonyms to the one-word form?

Comment: +1 this was only synonymized because of the number-of-questions-in-each-tag-restriction thingy.

Comment: Should it really be one word? There's no entry for 'downvote' in the [OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/noresults?dictionaryVersion=region-uk&isWritersAndEditors=true&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=downvote&searchUri=All&sort=alpha&type=dictionarysearch) or [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downvote).

Comment: @Rup "down vote" doesn't appear either; and yet if not a phrase, it would have to be "vote down" per English grammar rules, so it's just a matter of the dictionaries being behind because they don't recognize either form.

Comment: I think "down-vote" hyphenated is valid grammar as a compound noun.

Comment: Hmm, apparently e.se [thinks it's one word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/upvote-vs-up-vote-vs-up-vote). I still disagree. (Although we all agree that "down vote" without a hyphen is wrong.)

Comment: The one word form is roughly twice as common as the hyphenated form on meta.  It's an idiom that we use amongst ourselves.

Comment: I think _downvote_ is used for similitude with _downgrade_. Considered that the hyphen in tags is used instead of a space (e.g. "feature-request"), I think that "downvotes" is a better tag.